# Why do I have so many unanswered puzzles?

Tags: knowledge, anagram

I can't understand. I mean, I'm trying to be interesting. Maybe I'm just bad at this. Huh, maybe I should try clickbait... or something special... another type... no, not just another type... GOT IT! I KNOW HOW TO BE INTERESTING:

SomeoneInExistence, nee Parz, presents: THE INTERESTING PUZZLE:

Um... maybe it's bro-baabaasdid,africagreenlandfaroearuba,papgoago,heldi,virginiakentucky,heldi,thinloameggstores,orcai,unassigned,maybepensacola,maybegreenbay,somewhereineldoradoca,eggstores!

Huh, that's new. Maybe it's just gibberish, but given I'm typing it, it might be PUZZLES! Don't you love slogs through horrible anagrams? Well, if you do, call the toll-free numbers below!

1-866-274-0892

(Please don't really call this unless you need insurance)

Partials are fine, but I'd prefer parfaits. My answer, by the way, is not an answer, but a fashion statement. Not so much a fashion statement as an English fashion statement. Not so much an English fashion statement as an English statement.

PROGRESS THUS FAR:

> Stiv has part one, the ANAGRAMMING, CORRECT!

Hint one, because even my INTERESTING PUZZLE isn't interesting.

> The phone number leads to Right Track from Quicken Loans. Annagrammabanana is a good way to do this, then phone Quicken Loans and ask them if they have contacts in other countries' capitals.

Hint two, for Stiv.

> If I could give you **44** upvotes, I would. You solved part one!

Comment: I thought it was a meta post. Nevermind.

Comment: Then I would post it on the meta. Hmm?

Comment: Is rot13 (Cyrnfr qba'g ernyyl pnyy guvf hayrff lbh arrq vafhenapr) n pyhr be qb lbh ernyyl zrna vg?

Comment: @VarunW. If you google the number it's a real phone number for [Liberty Mutual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty_Mutual), a US insurer. So it's a genuine remark. The question is: does it also mean anything else, while just coincidentally also being this real phone number...?

Comment: Just a comment because not enough for an answer: rot13(fbzr bs gur abafrafr jbeqf urer ner nantenzf bs jbeyq pncvgnyf, yvxr fb: NQQVF NONON (Rguvbcvn), nsevpnterraynaqsnebrnehon, CNTB CNTB (Nzrevpna Fnzbn), QRYUV (Vaqvn), ivetvavnxraghpxl, QRYUV (Vaqvn), UNZVYGBA (Orezhqn) FG TRBETRF (Teranqn) PNVEB (Rtlcg), hanffvtarq, znlorcrafnpbyn, znlorterraonl, fbzrjurervaryqbenqbpn, FG TRBETRF (Teranqn)!) But I don't yet see what more to do with these.

Comment: That is CORRECT!!! Remember your insurance, and godspeed!

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Posting a partial answer with some discoveries so far (transferred from my comments on the question) and some thoughts on where this is going next...</sup>

---

Firstly, note that in the long string of seemingly disconnected words...

> ...several of the words here are [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram)s of capital cities of countries or territories around the world:
>
>  baabaasdid = **ADDIS ABABA** (Ethiopia),
>  *africagreenlandfaroearuba*,
>  papgoago = **PAGO PAGO** (American Samoa),
>  heldi = **DELHI** (India),
>  *virginiakentucky*,
>  heldi = **DELHI** (India),
>  thinloam = **HAMILTON** (Bermuda),
>  eggstores = **ST. GEORGE'S** (Grenada)
>  orcai = **CAIRO** (Egypt),
>  *unassigned*, *maybepensacola*, *maybegreenbay*, *somewhereineldoradoca*,
>  eggstores = **ST. GEORGE'S** (Grenada)

The next step seems like it should be something to do with...

> **international calling codes**, since we have reference to a telephone number in the puzzle, and the second hint appears to indicate the calling code for my home country, the UK (+44).
>
>  If we write out the calling codes for the cities in the anagrams we get:
>
>  Addis Ababa +251-1
>  Pago Pago +1-684
>  Delhi +91-11
>  Delhi +91-11
>  Hamilton +1-441
>  St. George's +1-473
>  Cairo +20-2
>  St. George's +1-473
>
>  (NB The country codes are substrings of these city codes.)
>
>  It may also be worth noting at this point that the phrases which were *not* anagrams could also potentially be converted to numbers via dialling codes here - most notably because (phrase 2) African countries, Greenland, the Faroe Islands and Aruba make up *all* of the nations whose calling code takes the form +2xx, suggesting that we may need to convert that part of the text to '2'... Some of these would need to be back-solved if this were the case though, particularly 'unassigned' (of which there are many such codes...).
>
>  What to do with these numbers then? It's tempting at first to try and convert these numbers into letters via A1Z26, but apart from a beguiling 'ASK AND' appearing across the two Delhis and Hamilton, this doesn't seem to lead anywhere just yet.
>
>  An alternative possibility is that the phone number in the puzzle isn't just fluff (or a pointer to think about calling codes) and is actually some kind of key for extracting letters out of the capitals/countries we have found. However, since the phone number contains a '9' and we only have 8 anagrams, this is unlikely.

Perhaps someone else can spot the next step...

Comment: Not the cities but the…